# MongoDb authentication to all the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

In MongoDB, Is there any way to add one time authentication to all the database with same username and password?

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/